# Number of styled elements in an HTML using JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

How can I count the number of all styled elements in an HTML using JSoup?
If the document object is doc, I do not mean this:

```
doc.select["*[style]"]
```

Because this just selects all elements which have style as an attribute, but I want to know the number of elements which style has been applied to in any way like by css or from header style.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `*[style]` selector and calling [`Elements.size()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#size--) method, e.g.

```
final String html = "<html><body><p>test</p><p style=\"color:red\"></p><span>aa</span><span style=\"font-size:10pt\">adasd</span></body></html>";

final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

final int count = doc.select("*[style]").size();

System.out.println("Count = " + count);
```

#### Output

```
Count = 2
```

Comment: As I explained, I do not want to count the number of elements which have style attribute. Sometimes style may be applied from the head or another .css file. I wanted to know if that is possible to count all of the elements which style have been applied to them in any way.

Comment: @Siavash Sorry for misunderstanding your question. Anyway, you can't select elements that have styles applied from CSS, because CSS file is not a part of DOM document and JSoup works only with DOM document tree. Applying CSS styles does not change anything in the DOM document structure, it's only a decoration applied by the web browser.

Comment: Yes, I figured out to read the CSS file and add the properties to all elements. Please update the answer so I will accept it as correct.